# How to handle different XML configurations for different deployments

Tags: deployment, versioning, xml, configuration

I am a software developer facing the following problem. Normally, I develop software and put client specific settings in a separate place (config file, database etc.). A new version of the software can therefore be installed by the client without losing those settings.

In my current project, the base is an external standard software, which needs to be adapted for the client's requirements. There are two ways to do this:

1. Configure the software. There are UIs for this to define all sorts of client specific things (regions, processes, interfaces etc.). Those settings can be exported as XML files.
2. Write code to do things.

The second point is not the problem, but how can I handle those XML configurations in a systematic way?

Examples:

- Client has seven plants, each with their own software installation and own configuration.
- Plant 1 has stricter quality requirements, so I configure some additional quality checks here. This is also reflected in the XML files.
- The legal name of the company changes and needs to be updated in all plant installations.
- Two out of the seven plants get a new machine type which will be configured. The others may get those at a later point.

My current idea is to use Git, have seven branches (one for each plant) and additional ones for each feature. The features could then be merged into the respective plants.

I'd like to get some more ideas regarding this scenario. I could imagine there is specialised software available for this sort of problem, generating configurations with rulesets (e.g. defining placeholders and inserting them dependent on the specific installation etc.). But I didn't find much about it.

Thanks!